# Program class is stuck/idle and does not execute remaining calls after 1st call in Anaconda/Command Line Prompt but works in Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to use the anaconda prompt to run my python script. It runs smoothly on the first call but stops there. I tried on Spyder, it works but I would like it to work on anaconda prompt or command line. Any reason why?

```
from decompress import decompress
from reddit import reddit
from clean import clean
from wikipedia import wikipedia

def main():
    dir_of_file = r"D:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\Reddit Data\Demo\\"
    print('0. Path: ' + dir_of_file)
    reddit_repo = reddit()
    wikipedia_repo = wikipedia()
    pattern_filter = "*2007*&*2008*"
    print('1. Creating data lake')
    reddit_repo.download_files(pattern_filter,"https://files.pushshift.io/reddit/submissions/",dir_of_file,'s') 
    reddit_repo.download_files(pattern_filter,"https://files.pushshift.io/reddit/comments/",dir_of_file,'c')         

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The RS Downloaded is this line of code being ran:

```
reddit_repo.download_files(pattern_filter,"https://files.pushshift.io/reddit/submissions/",dir_of_file,'s')
```

[image]
**Update:**

Added the class/function

```
class reddit:

    def multithread_download_files_func(self,list_of_file):
        filename = list_of_file[list_of_file.rfind("/")+1:]
        path_to_save_filename = self.ptsf_download_files + filename
        if not os.path.exists(path_to_save_filename): 
            data_content = None
            try:
                request = urllib.request.Request(list_of_file)
                response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
                data_content = response.read()
            except urllib.error.HTTPError:
                print('HTTP Error')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            if data_content:
                with open(path_to_save_filename, 'wb') as wf:    
                    wf.write(data_content)                 
                    print(self.present_download_files + filename)                        

    def download_files(self,filter_files_df,url_to_download_df,path_to_save_file_df,prefix):
        #do some processing
        matching_fnmatch_list.sort()

        p = ThreadPool(200)
        p.map(self.multithread_download_files_func, matching_fnmatch_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the download which was taking a lot of time. I have changed network and it worked as expected. So there is no issue with cmd or anaconda prompt